# How to use conda in atom terminal without typing in source ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, atom-editor

Recently I installed the platformio terminal for atom editor. When I open the terminal to run conda it said command not found. Although the conda runs fine in the normal terminal. I ran the source command on .bashrc and it worked. But I have to deal with this every time I restart atom. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the default shell instance. Go to the settings for platformio terminal in Atom and change the shell path. In my case the default shell was Powershell which does not launch conda. So, i changed the path here pointing to cmd.exe "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" & restarted the terminal and that sorted the problem for me. Perhaps, for Linux too you need to enter the ~/.bashrc path here and restart the terminal

[image]